# pyodbc/sql - Newly created tables are going to Master database and not specified database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, pyodbc

I am working on a project for class, where I am using Python to create a database and tables in my 2016 SQL Server.  I have installed pyodbc and was able to establish a connection between Python and my SQL Server.  However, when I run my code, I am able to create the 'mydatabase' database...but the subsequent tables that I want to create are going to the 'Tables' folder in the 'Master' database.

I have tried it both with creating the database and the tables in the same Python file, as well as only adding the tables.  The result is always the same - it goes to the Master database, and not the 'mydatabase' database.  I've done quite a bit of Googling, and it seems like I have the code written correctly; so, I am not sure what to look at now.

Here is the code for creating the database and tables in one fair swoop...

```
import pyodbc

mydb = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-5I015MM\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

mydb.autocommit = True

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")

Q1 = "CREATE TABLE Contact(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, \
        username varchar(255) NOT NULL, password varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        firstName varchar(255) NOT NULL, middleName varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        lastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, address varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        officePhone varchar(15) NOT NULL, cellPhone varchar(15) NOT NULL, \
        email varchar(255) NOT NULL)"
mycursor.execute(Q1)

Q2 = "CREATE TABLE Manufacturer(name varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY, \
        registeredCountry varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        contactPerson INT NOT NULL, \
        FOREIGN KEY(contactPerson) REFERENCES Contact(id))"
mycursor.execute(Q2)

Q3 = "CREATE TABLE TestLab(name varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY, \
        address varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        contactPerson INT NOT NULL, \
        FOREIGN KEY(contactPerson) REFERENCES Contact(id))"
mycursor.execute(Q3)

Q4 = "CREATE TABLE Product(modelNumber varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY, \
        manufacturer varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        maufacturingDate date NOT NULL, \
        prodLength decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, \
        prodWidth decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, \
        cellTechnology varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        cableType varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        maximumSystemVoltage varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        ratedVoc decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        ratedIsc decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        ratedVmp decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        ratedImp decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        ratedPmp decimal(4,1) NOT NULL, \
        ratedFf decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        FOREIGN KEY(manufacturer) REFERENCES Manufacturer(name))"
mycursor.execute(Q4)

Q5 = "CREATE TABLE TestResults(dataSource varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        modelNumber varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        reportingCondition varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        testSequence varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        testDate date NOT NULL, \
        isc decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        voc decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        imp decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        vmp decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        pmp decimal(4,1) NOT NULL, \
        ff decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        noct decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        PRIMARY KEY(dataSource, modelNumber), \
        FOREIGN KEY(dataSource) REFERENCES TestLab(name), \
        FOREIGN KEY(modelNumber) REFERENCES Product(modelNumber))"
mycursor.execute(Q5)
```

And here is the code for just creating the tables in the 'mydatabase' database, if the database already existed in SQL...

```
import pyodbc

mydb = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-5I015MM\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=mydatabase;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

mydb.autocommit = True

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

Q1 = "CREATE TABLE Contact(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, \
        username varchar(255) NOT NULL, password varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        firstName varchar(255) NOT NULL, middleName varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        lastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, address varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        officePhone varchar(15) NOT NULL, cellPhone varchar(15) NOT NULL, \
        email varchar(255) NOT NULL)"
mycursor.execute(Q1)

Q2 = "CREATE TABLE Manufacturer(name varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY, \
        registeredCountry varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        contactPerson INT NOT NULL, \
        FOREIGN KEY(contactPerson) REFERENCES Contact(id))"
mycursor.execute(Q2)

Q3 = "CREATE TABLE TestLab(name varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY, \
        address varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        contactPerson INT NOT NULL, \
        FOREIGN KEY(contactPerson) REFERENCES Contact(id))"
mycursor.execute(Q3)

Q4 = "CREATE TABLE Product(modelNumber varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY, \
        manufacturer varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        maufacturingDate date NOT NULL, \
        prodLength decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, \
        prodWidth decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, \
        cellTechnology varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        cableType varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        maximumSystemVoltage varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        ratedVoc decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        ratedIsc decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        ratedVmp decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        ratedImp decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        ratedPmp decimal(4,1) NOT NULL, \
        ratedFf decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        FOREIGN KEY(manufacturer) REFERENCES Manufacturer(name))"
mycursor.execute(Q4)

Q5 = "CREATE TABLE TestResults(dataSource varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        modelNumber varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        reportingCondition varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        testSequence varchar(255) NOT NULL, \
        testDate date NOT NULL, \
        isc decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        voc decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        imp decimal(3,2) NOT NULL, \
        vmp decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        pmp decimal(4,1) NOT NULL, \
        ff decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        noct decimal(3,1) NOT NULL, \
        PRIMARY KEY(dataSource, modelNumber), \
        FOREIGN KEY(dataSource) REFERENCES TestLab(name), \
        FOREIGN KEY(modelNumber) REFERENCES Product(modelNumber))"
mycursor.execute(Q5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the row
    `Mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")`
Add
    `mycursor.execute("USE mydatabase")`

Comment: It worked!!  I feel so silly missing that.  Thank you so much, @Vekonomen !!